# Monster movie involves survivors trapped in a planet with three or more moons

Tags: story-identification, movie

I haven't been able to watch the full movie. Just saw a particular scene. In this scene, the survivors were trapped inside a cabin in the jungle. There were to person near a table which had a humanoid body (perhaps the offspring of main monster which was larger than the cabin) on it. One character uses a pen to puncture the belly and a acidic liquid comes out damaging the pen and killing the other character.

There was another scene where a person accidentally goes outside the cabin (can't remember; may be to collect something from outside), the monster would stampede and split that person in half. At some point, the monster would damage the cabin. Then the survivors would choose to leave the cabin when the monster was not around. When they were outside, I noticed that there was three/five moons in the sky. However, I couldn't get to watch it after that.

The movie was maybe released around 2009-2011.

Comment: But the difference is that here the monster is at least as tall as a two storey building

Comment: Honorable mention for *Pitch Black*, which has the moons, the monsters, the people trapped inside, but not the jungle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Action thriller [Ferocious Planet](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1637728/) from 2011.

> A groundbreaking device is designed to glimpse alternate universes. But when the machine malfunctions and transports a group of observers into a nightmarish dimension of alien terrors, the travelers must use ingenuity to survive.

Everything you mentioned is there: The multiple moons, the huge monsters, the guy split in half, and the guy dying from puncturing a baby monster with a pen and being sprayed with acid - a scene which you can glimpse near the end of the trailer: